# Perl/DBI - Insert rows from Postgres to an Oracle table

Tags: perl, dbi

I am trying to write a script that will read the data from postgresql table and insert it to an oracle table, here is my script :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use DBI;
use warnings FATAL => qw(all);

my $pgh = pgh(); # connect to postgres
my $ora = ora(); # connect to oracle
my @rows;
my $rows =[] ;
my $placeholders = join ", ", ("?") x @rows;

my $sth = $pgh->prepare('SELECT * FROM "Employees"');
$sth->execute();
 while (@rows = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    $ora->do("INSERT INTO employees VALUES($placeholders)");
 }

#connect to postgres
sub pgh {
my $dsn = 'DBI:Pg:dbname=northwind;host=localhost';
my $user = 'postgres';
my $pwd  = 'postgres';
my $pgh = DBI -> connect($dsn,$user,$pwd,{'RaiseError' => 1});
return $pgh;
}

#connect to oracle
sub ora {
my $dsn = 'dbi:Oracle:host=localhost;sid=orcl';
my $user = 'nwind';
my $pwd  = 'nwind';
my $ora = DBI -> connect($dsn,$user,$pwd,{'RaiseError' => 1});
return $ora;
}
```

I am getting the following error :

```
DBD::Oracle::db do failed: ORA-00936: missing expression (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 29 in 'INSERT INTO employees VALUES(<*>)') [for Statement "INSERT INTO employees VALUES()"] at /usr/share/perlproj/cgi-bin/scripts/nwind_pg2ora.pl line 19.
```

Please help me to get my code correct.
Many thanks !!
Tonya.

Comment: Your `@rows` is empty when `$placeholders` gets created, perhaps it would be good to read one row, then recreate `$placeholders` before setting up `$ora->do(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for DBD::Oracle you have to bind the parameter value for the BLOBs like :

```
use DBD::Oracle qw(:ora_types); 
$sth->bind_param($idx, $value, { ora_type=>ORA_BLOB, ora_field=>'PHOTO' });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my @rows;
my $rows =[] ;

my $sth = $pgh->prepare('SELECT * FROM "Employees"');
$sth->execute();
while (@rows = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    my $placeholders = join ", ", ("?") x @rows;
    $ora->do("INSERT INTO employees VALUES($placeholders)");
}
```

You're joining an empty @rows to create an empty $placeholders.
perform the join inside the while loop, before the do().

Answer (score 0):

The following lazily creates a statement handle for inserting into the Oracle database based off the number of columns in the returned records.

It then inserts those column values into the database, so obviously we're assuming the table structures are identical:

```
use strict;
use DBI;
use warnings FATAL => qw(all);

my $pgh = pgh(); # connect to postgres
my $ora = ora(); # connect to oracle

my $sth = $pgh->prepare('SELECT * FROM "Employees"');
$sth->execute();

my $sth_insert;

while (my @cols = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    $sth_insert ||= do {
        my $placeholders = join ", ", ("?") x @cols;
        $ora->prepare("INSERT INTO employees VALUES ($placeholders)");
    };
    $sth_insert->execute(@cols);
}
```

Comment: Thanks much !! there is a problem the employees table in postgres has a column with datatype of BYTEA and inserting into oracle datatype of BLOB and its choking on that, is there a way I can insert raw data of BYTEA to a BLOB in oracle using DBI - Tonya

Comment: I do not know as I haven't used Oracle myself.  I would suggest that this is a new problem and that you should ask about it specifically.

Comment: Have you looked at the DBD::Oracle module docs have to say on the subject of working with Oracle LOBs?   http://search.cpan.org/~pythian/DBD-Oracle-1.74/lib/DBD/Oracle.pm#LOBS_AND_LONGS